# ERROR: Could not build wheels for gfootball, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, cmake, multi-agent-reinforcement-learning

I am trying to install open-source game "[football](https://github.com/google-research/football) environment" in a remote cluster which I do not have sudo permission. My steps to install the environment:

```
git clone https://github.com/google-research/football.git
cd football/
python3 -m pip install .
```

I also tried pip install method

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools psutil wheel
python3 -m pip install gfootball
```

Here is my error message:

```
     -- Found OpenGL: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/lib/libOpenGL.so
      -- Found EGL: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/lib/libEGL.so
      -- Found SDL2_image: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/lib/libSDL2_image.so
      -- Found SDL2_ttf: /cvmfs/soft.computecanada.ca/gentoo/2020/usr/lib/libSDL2_ttf.so
      CMake Error at CMakeModules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:110 (MESSAGE):
        Could NOT find SDL2_gfx (missing: SDL2_GFX_LIBRARIES SDL2_GFX_INCLUDE_DIRS)
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeModules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:301 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
        CMakeModules/FindSDL2_gfx.cmake:99 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
        CMakeLists.txt:61 (FIND_PACKAGE)
      
      
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/home/football/third_party/gfootball_engine/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      gfootball/build_game_engine.sh: line 30: pushd: third_party/gfootball_engine: No such file or directory
      error: Google Research Football compilation failed
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gfootball
  Running setup.py clean for gfootball
Failed to build gfootball
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gfootball, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

How can I solve this installation error?